# Gauge Needle Pivot Point

Tags: c#, winforms

My math skills are not good. I've searched the Internet and cannot figure this out.

I'm having a hard time trying to keep a speedometer type gauge needle positioned.

The gauge is half a circle or 180 degrees. The needle is a png image that is 10 pixels wide and 164 pixels high.

The gauge is 378 pixels wide and 226 pixels high.

Because I'm trying to rotate a tall rectangle the needle position must me recalculated.

```
Point pivotPoint = new Point(gauge.Width / 2, gauge.Height); 
double degrees = -45; // example where to point the needle
```

Can someone please give me some actual lines of C# code that will keep the needle png correctly positioned?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Here's another idea -> Expand the needle's image (with transparent background) to a square and rotate it. This way you won't have to recalculate the position

Comment: It's already on a transparent background and on a rectangle - I already tried a square but still does not help. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is you can expand the image so the needle will act as a radius. This way when you rotate it the center will stay fixed at the location you want it

Comment: I think I know what you mean now - If i cannot get it to work mathematically I will use a large box container.

I don't know why someone voted this down. I have other talents and just trying to learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that draws a rotated needle image onto a PictureBox with a gauge image.

I take the angle from a trackbar that goes from 0 to 180.

The Needle stands upright upside down:

- The angle makes up for the 90° offset we begin with.
- The rotation point of the needle should be with its origin.

The PictureBox.SizeMode is set to Autosize.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Bitmap needle =  new Bitmap("D:\\needle3.png" )  )
    {
        int angle = trBar_angle.Value;
        label1.Text = angle.ToString("###0°");

        // this is the offset after the translation
        Point targetPoint = new Point(-needle.Width / 2, needle.Width / 2);

        // shortcuts for the sizes
        Size nSize = needle.Size;
        Size pSize = pictureBox1.ClientSize;

        // this is the translation of the graphic to meet the rotation point
        int transX = pSize.Width / 2;
        int transY = pSize.Height - nSize.Width / 2;

        //set the rotation point and rotate
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform( transX, transY );
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle + 90); 

        // draw on the rotated graphics
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(needle, targetPoint);

        //reset everything
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform( -angle - 90); 
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform( -transX, -transY );

    }

}
```

My needle:
[image]
and the result:
[image]

I hope you have a nicer gauge than the one I made  ;-)