# How to use windows forms report with radial gauge

Tags: c#, windows, forms, controls, report

I tried to find information on how to use a radial gauge in a windows form report.
I really can't find anything on this. Not sure if there is not much info on this.
Is there anyone who can get me some info on this? How would I be able to use a value from a text box in a report viewer to show this on a radial gauge and even using a track bar to get some idea how to use it.

Even if getting a small example to build on this would be really great :-)

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Can you show an image? Do you want a Chart maybe? What kind of 'reort' o you mean?

Comment: Hi, I have the standard installation from Visual Studio 2010, and I'm not able to install other plugins etc because of company policies.
I wanted to add a radial gauge on a report, and it would get the data from an access database. Just a simple thing to get me started and build on it more complex things.
Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options even without any external stuff.

- You can draw a gauge needle onto a gauge image. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721646/gauge-needle-pivot-point/24746389#24746389) is an example.
- You can draw the needle onto an image by either calulating the outer point and drawing a line to the center or by rotating the canvas as in the link.
- Or you can use the built-in MSChart control and its Doughnut charttype.

Here is an example for this:

[image]

The code is simple:

- first we set up the chart by adding three `DataPoints`; then we code a function to update the value.

The points are for

- the open, transparent part
- the value of the gauge in green
- the rest of the scale in red

For testing I use these variables:

```
double valMin = 0;        // user data minimum
double valMax = 100;      // ~ maximum
float angle = 60;         // open pie angle at the bottom
string valFmt = "{0}°";  // a format string
```

My current value is pulled from a trackbar.

Setup code:

```
void setupChartGauge(double val, double vMin, double vMax, float a)
{
    valMin = vMin;
    valMax = vMax;
    angle = a;
    Series s = gaugeChart.Series[0];
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
    s.SetCustomProperty("PieStartAngle", (90 - angle/2) + "");
    s.SetCustomProperty("DoughnutRadius",  "10");
    s.Points.Clear();
    s.Points.AddY(angle);
    s.Points.AddY(0);
    s.Points.AddY(0);
    setChartGauge(0);
    s.Points[0].Color = Color.Transparent;
    s.Points[1].Color = Color.Chartreuse;
    s.Points[2].Color = Color.Tomato;
}
```

and setting a value:

```
void setChartGauge(double val)
{
    Series s = gaugeChart.Series[0];
    double range = valMax - valMin;
    double aRange = 360 - angle;
    double f = aRange / range;

    double v1 = val * f;
    double v2 = (range - val) * f;
    s.Points[1].YValues[0] = v1;
    s.Points[2].YValues[0] = v2;

    gaugeChart.Titles[0].Text = String.Format(valFmt, val); 
    gaugeChart.Refresh();
}
```

I have added minimal styling:

- The `Chart` has a `Title` docked centered bottom which I also update
- I have set a back color
- I paint an inner circle in the `Paint` event like so:

---

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
Rectangle r = chart1.ClientRectangle;
r.Inflate(-10, -10);
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(55, Color.Beige)))
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, r);
```

Note that `Pie` and `Doughnut` charts can have only **one** series. To show a 2nd one you would need an **overlapping** 2nd chartarea with the exact same `Position`.

There are infinite ways to draw stuff, both from scratch or updating the MsChart control. Various gradient brushes come to mind. Adding ticks and a needle will involve rotation code, which basically consists of 3 lines of code..

**Update:**

Here is an example of drawing a gauge needle.

The code should be called from a `Paint` event and should pass out a valid `Graphics` object (read: `e.Graphics`), a `float` for the data value, a `Rectangle` to place the gauge in, a `Color` and a `float` for the percentage of the rectangle size to use.

```
private void drawNeedle(Graphics g, float val, Rectangle r, Color c, float length)
{
    Point pc = new Point(r.X + r.Width / 2, r.Y + r.Height / 2);
    Point p2 = new Point((int)( pc.X + r.Width / 2  * length / 100f), pc.Y);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(c, 3f)
    { StartCap = LineCap.RoundAnchor, EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor })
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.TranslateTransform(pc.X, pc.Y);
        g.RotateTransform(val - (270 - angle / 2));
        g.TranslateTransform(-pc.X, -pc.Y);
        g.DrawLine(pen, pc, p2);
        g.ResetTransform();
    }
}
```

You can use it in any control that support owner-drawing including the chart..:

```
drawNeedle(e.Graphics, (float)gaugeChart.Series[0].Points[1].YValues[0], r, Color.White, 70f);
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot :-) 
there is only one little tiny thing, I'm not to good yet with C# and putting the above in the form code window etc is only confusing me. Are you able to upload this as a solution/project so I can open on my side and then learn how it works? would be really saving me from pulling my hair a lot :-)

Comment: It is part of a test suite, so no this more than a tiny thing for me. But the steps are really simple: Add this using clause: `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`. Then drag a Chart from the Data toolbox. Go to its properties and add one to the Titles collection.  Style it as it suits you. Add the four variables at class level. Call the setup code from somewhere, e.g. form.Load or later. Finally, when your data change call the setChartGauge function. Seven simple steps..

Comment: If you run into problems do ping me for help!

Comment: hi, if you can upload this example , it will help me a lot as I'm lost and can't get the logic :-(

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example with a TrackBar:

```
private Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Gauge.RadialGauge radialGauge1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
private Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Gauge.Needle needle1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
     this.needle1 = new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Gauge.Needle();
     this.needle1.Value = 0F;

     this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
     this.radialGauge1 = new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Gauge.RadialGauge();
     this.trackBar1.Value = (int) needle1.Value;

     this.radialGauge1.EnableCustomNeedles = true;
     this.radialGauge1.NeedleCollection.Add(needle1);
     this.radialGauge1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(230, 230);
     this.radialGauge1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
}
```

And a scroll event which sync between gauge and trackBar:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        needle1.Value = trackBar1.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code :-)
Do I need to add some references?

Comment: Sure. you need to download the Syncfusion references for WinForms from [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads)

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do it without adding external plugins or references from other tools?

Comment: [AquaGauge](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20341/Aqua-Gauge) is free and full of examples.